# MPI_Comm_size always returns 1

Tags: c, ubuntu, cmake, mpi

MPI_Comm_size command always returns single process, when processors count is 4. I'm using MPI 3.2.1 with CLion on virtual xUbuntu 16.04. Emulator - VMWare. On vm settings processors count is set to 4, nproc in xUbuntu says "4".

Here's output for `whereis mpicc`:

```
mpicc: /usr/local/bin/mpicc
```

I'v tried with mpi 1.**, but it alse did the same. What's wrong?

Here is CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(primes)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(primes ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/mpicc")
```

Here is the part of code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

...

int rank, tasksCount;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tasksCount);
```

**UPD**
Running though console:

```
kamo@kamo:~/prog/primes$ mpicc -o main.o main.c
kamo@kamo:~/prog/primes$ mpiexec -np 4 ./mail.o
```

gives nothing. Nothing happens and nothing is written to console. Just new line without "kamo@kamo:~/prog/primes$" prefix.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing `mpirun` from one lib and your app is not linked with `libmpi.so` from an other lib/version

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I wonder if OP is using `mpirun` at all!

Comment: Good point ! A MPI application must be launched via `mpirun` or `mpiexec` otherwise this is known as singleton mode and only one MPI task runs.

Comment: Are you running something like `mpirun -np 4 primes`?

Comment: @francis
Added mpirun/mpiexec results to question.

Comment: But I was always trying to run through CLion debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried from the very beginning and it worked fine.

CLion debugger works wrong, so you should use mpicc + mpiexec commands as described in UPD block of my question.